# Sum each row of a numpy array with all rows of second numpy array (python)

Tags: python, numpy, sum, row

I would like to know if there is any fast way to sum each row of a first array with all rows of a second array. In this case both arrays have the same number of colulmns. For instance if `array1.shape = (n,c)` and `array2.shape = (m,c)`, the resulting array would be an `array3.shape = ((n*m), c)`

Look at the example below:

```
array1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                   [3, 4, 5],
                   [6, 7, 8]])

array2 = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                   [3, 4, 5]])
```

The result would be:

```
array3 = np.array([[0,  2,  4],
                   [3,  5,  7]
                   [3,  5,  7]
                   [6,  8, 10]
                   [6,  8, 10]
                   [9, 11, 13]])
```

The only way I see I can do this is to repeat each row of one of the arrays the number of rows of the other array. For instance, by doing `np.repeat(array1, len(array2), axis=0)` and then sum this array with `array2`. This is not very practical however if the number of rows is too big. The other way would be with a for loop but this is too slow.

Any other better way to do it..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `np.vstack([array2 + x for x in array1])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `array1` to `3D` so that it becomes broadcastable against `2D` array2 and then perform broadcasted addition and a final reshape is needed for desired output -

```
In [30]: (array1[:,None,:] + array2).reshape(-1,array1.shape[1])
Out[30]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 3,  5,  7],
       [ 3,  5,  7],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [ 9, 11, 13]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following inline code if you haven't already. This is the simplest and probably also the quickest on a single thread.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
...                    [3, 4, 5],
...                    [6, 7, 8]])
>>> 
>>> array2 = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
...                    [3, 4, 5]])
>>> array3 = np.array([i+j for i in array1 for j in array2])
>>> array3
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 3,  5,  7],
       [ 3,  5,  7],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [ 9, 11, 13]])
>>>
```

If you are looking for speed up by treading, you could consider using `CUDA` or [multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm). This suggestion goes a bit out of scope of your question but gives you an idea of what can be done to speed up matrix operations.